# How to grep a whole word containg a dot (.)

Tags: bash, grep

My file contains the following text

```
xyz.com       123  321
xyz.com.br    123  123
abcd.xyz.com  123  321
```

I want to grep the line which contains xyz.com alone.
ie, the output should be the first line.

```
 xyz.com   123  321
```

Tried the following but no avail.

```
grep "^xyz.com$" file.txt
grep '^xyz.com$' file.txt
grep -w xyz.com file.txt
grep '^xyz.com$' file.txt
grep '^xyz\.com$' file.txt
grep -Fx xyz.com file.txt
grep -w 'xyz.com' file.txt
grep -w 'xyz\.com' file.txt
grep '\sxyz.com\s' file.txt
grep '\bxyz.com\b' file.txt
grep "\bxyz.com\b" file.txt
grep "\<xyz.com\>" file.txt
grep '\<xyz.com\>' file.txt
grep -w -l "xyz\.com" file.txt
grep -w "xyz\.com" file.txt
grep -wF "xyz\.com" file.txt
grep -w "xyz\.com$" file.txt
grep -w "xyz\.com\$" file.txt
```

Shell is bash.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your example the line does not contain xyz.com alone, it contains more columns with numbers. This is why `'^xyz\.com$'` did not work.
Try:

```
grep '^xyz\.com\s' file.text
```

The added `\s` at the expression end, force a space character right after the searched string and allow other text after.

To include the case of a line with only the search string try:

```
grep '^xyz\.com\(\s.*\)\?$' file.txt
```

It will allow line end right after the  string but require a space in any other case.

See [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) for more information on regular expressions.

Comment: What grep are you using that uses perl syntax for whitespace by default? Just curious...

Comment: @blm, GNU grep 2.16 on ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Thanks. I'm using gnu grep but it's an older version and perl syntax doesn't work without -P. Time to upgrade...

Answer (score 0):

```
$ grep '^xyz\.com[[:space:]]' file.txt
xyz.com      123 321
$ grep -P '^xyz\.com\s' file.txt
xyz.com      123 321
```

The first uses the POSIXy way of matching whitespace, the second use the perly way, which means you need to specify with `-P` using perl regular expressions.